# loop asynctask android is executing only last value in loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask, getjson, http-get

I have an array of integers which needs to be called one after another in a loop from url .I have the code below and it calls the last number multiple times but all the numbers from the beginning is skipped .How do I make this to work.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
 final String[] ar={"1","2","3",.............,"25"}

                 for (  j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {


                         u="http://www.example.com/"+ar[j];

                        JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();        
                        new MyAsyncTask().execute(u);

                }


    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = ""; 

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            String url_select = params[0];
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url_select));

                // receive response as inputStream
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
//
//              // Read content & Log
//              inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
                Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
                e3.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e4) {
                Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Convert response to string using String Builder
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                inputStream.close();
                result = sBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("StringBuilding & BufferedReader", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        } // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)


        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

            //parse JSON data
            try{
                JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);


                // End Loop

                this.progressDialog.dismiss();

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

            } // catch (JSONException e)
       catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)

    } //class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String url_select = parms[0];
```

If you want parallel execution you should use a executor. I suggest you use a executor instead of executing asynctask in a for loop.

```
new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "url1","url2"..);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Params...)

Check order of execution @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @jason url1,url2 is an example. It does not matter whether its dynamic or not. Its better to use executor for parallel execution if you are not bothered about the order of execution. if you are bothered about the order you can use Serial executor.

Comment: @jason you are welcome glad to help. Using executor is a better option since its is parallel execution

Comment: I am trying to save the data which I recieve to txt file and append the data but its not writing .I am doing that on post execute.Can you tell me why ?Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @jason post a new question with relevant code. It' difficult says what happening without looking at the code

Comment: Hello Sir I have posted the new question .Please look into it.Thanks you for your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757778/unable-to-save-data-to-txt-in-loop-asynctask

Comment: @jason i see no change you have not used a executor

Comment: I am sorry I have not pasted the executor code .Its edited now.

Answer (score 2):

in doInBackground you should use

```
url_select = params[0];
```

instead of
 url_select = u;
(you assign u in the for loop while executing the task asynchronously so you cant' really know which value u has, when the task is executed...and eventually it keeps the last value that you assigned..)

Comment: will this call work  "new MyAsyncTask().execute(u);"

Comment: yes that call is correct. and the param that you pass to execute will be available in doInBackground as param[0]

Answer (score 1):

`String url_select = u;`

I think the problem is here you are using a hardcoded value here You should get the passed value from `params`

`String url_select = params[0];`

Comment: will this call work  "new MyAsyncTask().execute(u);"