# unable to save data to txt in loop asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to save every output data in asynctask for each http call.But I am unable to see any data in a file.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
     final String[] ar={"1","2","3",.............,"25"}

        filename="test_file";       
            myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+filename);
                 try {
                        myFile.createNewFile();
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 


                         for (  j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {


                                 u="http://www.example.com/"+ar[j];

                                JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();        


             new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,u);

                        }


                               try {
                            myOutWriter.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

    }


            class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

                private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = ""; 

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                            MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
         String url_select = params[0];
                    try {

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url_select));

                        // receive response as inputStream
                        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        //
        //              // Read content & Log
        //              inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
                        Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                        Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e4) {
                        Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
                        e4.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Convert response to string using String Builder
                    try {
                        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                        inputStream.close();
                        result = sBuilder.toString();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("StringBuilding & BufferedReader", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    }
                    return null;
                } // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)


                protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

                    //parse JSON data
                    try{
                        JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);



                        String name = jArray.getString("name");


                              if (name!=null) {


                        Log.w("idname", name);


//
                    myOutWriter.append(name).append("\r\n");
//                  
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), name, 5).show();
                    }

                        // End Loop

                        this.progressDialog.dismiss();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

                    } // catch (JSONException e)
               catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                } // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)

            } //class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
```

Comment: change u to params[0] in do inBackground method

Comment: Log `name` in `onPostExecute` and check the logcat

Comment: @jason why this in for loop `new MyAsyncTask().execute(u);` and this
 `new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,u);`?. You can pass the array of urls to doInbackground and download data there. No need to call execute in for loop. Also did you log name and check in logcat?

Comment: @Raghunandan Sorry sir my BAD .I had not posted your code .Its edited now.The log name is working.

Comment: @Raghunandan,@raj I am getting exception : java.io.IOException: OutputStreamWriter is closed

Comment: It seems that the OutputStream myOutWriter is closed before you write data in it

Comment: @Ivan where should I place it in the code below ?

Comment: @Raghunandan Basically how do I save these names to file ?Thanks for your time.I guess myOutWriter is closed early.How do I save data from asynctask above to list?

Comment: @jason you see only one name in log right?. yes looks like  `myOutWriter`  before you write data.

Comment: @Raghunandan   yes and exception in logcat

Comment: @jason make sure you do the writing in doInbackground and close the writer at the last when no needed. that should fix the exception

Comment: I cannot do in background as result is json object which I am parsing getting it in on postexecute.Should I parse json in do in background if yes then my asyntask will have not return type .Can you edit the code above please .Thanks

Comment: @jason yes you can parse you json in doInbackground also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (  j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
     u="http://www.example.com/"+ar[j];
     JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();        
     new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,u);
  }
  try {
       myOutWriter.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

You close the myOutWriter after start MyAsyncTask. So when MyAsyncTask try to write data to file, it throw OutputStreamWriter is closed exception.

You need remove the code of close myOutWriter from here. Add add close code at the end of onPostExecute like below:

```
void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                .....

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

                } // catch (JSONException e)
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int count = taskCount.decrementAndGet()
                if(count == 0 ) {
                    try {
                      myOutWriter.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
```

the definition of taskCount is like this:

```
AtomicInteger taskCount = new AtomicInteger(ar.length - 1);
```

At last, I think Thread and CountDownLatch is better option

Answer (score 0):

check if entity not null then write to db

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if(entity!=null ){
 inputStream = entity.getContent();
}
```